# Sometimes a critical hit doesn't announce itself on screen or make the "bong! sound.

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Sometimes a critical hit doesn't announce itself on screen or make the "bong!" sound. This usually happens when multiple critical hits are being scored (or are they?) very quickly. Is the absence of the CritHit "bong!" sound just programming put there to keep the game from sounding like a drum circle at Burning Man, or is there a mandatory time delay in which CritHits cannot be scored?

Comment: Maybe it’s script lag.

Comment: How do you know that there are multiple crits at all if there's no mention of them?

Comment: There is most likely a delay in the audio to prevent multiple annoying sound effects from triggering too close to each other.  If you use double dagger sneak power attack, you can score 5 sneak attack critical hits within a second.  I will only hear the first one go off.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the scripting gets glitched out and some actions won't give out results. I recommend that you download the Unofficial Patch if you're on PC, it makes fixes for stuff, and even fixes scripts so your game would be glitch free. If you're on console, there's nothing I can find out to help you.